# How to upgrade to iOS 5.1.1 on first generation iPad

Tags: ipad

i have just had this iPad passed down to me. I'm not that familiar yet, I'm trying to download some games, some need iOS 6+ that's fine, but some it tell me I need 5.1.1? I'm probably being daft but I thought that's what I'm on? I'm 1st generation, no frills iPad and am used for web browsing and music/music writing mainly. I have completed the games it had on it already and would like new ones, free new ones lol!
   Can you help me please, I've been scanning the web but no joy! 
                   Thankyou x

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current version of iOS that is installed on the device by going to Settings → General → About and check the version number.

To update your device, connect it to iTunes over USB and click Update.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update any further than iOS 5.1.1

Comment: Cruel, but true.